# Image intensity distribution changes during opencv warp affine

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am using python 3.8.5 and opencv 4.5.1 on windows 7

I am using the following code to rotate images.

```
def pad_rotate(image, ang, pad, pad_value=0):

    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    
    #create larger image and paste original image at the center.
    # this is done to avoid any cropping during rotation

    nH, nW = h + 2*pad, w + 2*pad  #new height and width

    cY, cX = nW//2, nH//2  #center of the new image

    #create new image with pad_values
    newImg = np.zeros((h+2*pad, w+2*pad), dtype=image.dtype)
    newImg[:,:] = pad_value

    #paste new image at the center
    newImg[pad:pad+h, pad:pad+w] = image

    #rotate CCW (for positive angles)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center=(cX, cY), angle=ang, scale=1.0)

    rotImg = cv2.warpAffine(newImg, M, (nW, nH), cv2.INTER_CUBIC, 
                        borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=pad_value)

return rotImg
```

My issue is that after the rotation, image intensity distribution is different than original.

**Following part of the question is edited to clarify the issue**

```
img = np.random.rand(500,500)
Rimg = pad_rotate(img, 15, 300, np.nan)
```

Here is what these images look like:
[image: img]
[image: Rimg]

Their intensities have clearly shifted:

```
np.percentile(img, [20, 50, 80])   
# prints  array([0.20061218, 0.50015415, 0.79989986])


np.nanpercentile(Rimg, [20, 50, 80])
# prints array([0.32420028, 0.50031483, 0.67656537])
```

Can someone please tell me how to avoid this normalization?

Comment: use an arbitrary but *showable* image to demonstrate. show input and output.

Comment: Your plotting tool may be changing the color map used when displaying or saving the image. Check to see if you can set it to a fixed color map. Or perhaps just save your result with OpenCV cv2.imsave()

Comment: due to cubic sampling, pixels in the result image will be calculated from *multiple* source pixels. the result is a blended value. the distribution's shape will change. `np.random.rand` is a uniform distribution with mean 0.5, so the values will be pulled towards that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The averaging effect of the interpolation changes the distribution...

Note:

- There is a mistake in your code sample (not related to the percentiles).
  The 4'th argument of `warpAffine` is `dst`.
  replace `cv2.warpAffine(newImg, M, (nW, nH), cv2.INTER_CUBIC` with:

  ```
   cv2.warpAffine(newImg, M, (nW, nH), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC
  ```

I tried to simplify the code sample that reproduces the problem.
The code sample uses linear interpolation, 1 degree rotation, and no NaN values.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((img.shape[1]//2, img.shape[0]//2), 1, 1)  # Rotate by 1 degree

Rimg = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR) # Use Linear interpolation

Rimg = Rimg[20:-20, 20:-20]  # Crop the part without the margins.

print(np.percentile(img, [20, 50, 80]))   #[0.20005696 0.49990526 0.79954818]
print(np.percentile(Rimg, [20, 50, 80]))  #[0.32244747 0.4998595  0.67698961]

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('Rimg', Rimg)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

When we disable the interpolation,
`Rimg = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)`
The percentiles are: [0.19943713 0.50004768 0.7995525 ].

---

Simpler example for showing that averaging elements changes the distribution:

```
A = np.random.rand(10000000)
B = (A[0:-1:2] + A[1::2])/2  # Averaging every two elements.
print(np.percentile(A, [20, 50, 80]))  # [0.19995436 0.49999472 0.80007232]
print(np.percentile(B, [20, 50, 80]))  # [0.31617922 0.50000145 0.68377251]
```

---

Why does interpolation skews the distribution towered the median?

I am not a mathematician.
I am sure you can get a better explanation...

Here is an intuitive example:
Assume there is list of values with uniform distribution in range [0, 1].
Assume there is a zero value in the list:
`[0.2, 0.7, 0, 0.5... ]`

After averaging every two sequential elements, the probability for getting a zero element in the output list is very small (only two sequential zeros result a zero).

The example shows that averaging pushes the extreme values towered the center.

Comment: **summing** (averaging) of random variables **convolves** their probability distributions. for uniform distributions, this will approach a gaussian. practical example with dies: single die: 1/6 uniform probability. two dice: triangle shape of probabilities. more dice: approaches a gaussian. see those plots: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and easy to understand explanation.